# C#: Trying to use control elements in different class - "object reference is required"

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am brand new to C# (I apologise if my question is noobish - I'm teaching myself, so it's a bumpy process). I am trying to develop a winform and since some of the methods are pretty long, I am trying to keep it in a couple classes. This is what I'm kind of hoping to achieve:

```
public partial class formMainForm : Form
{
    public formMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void UpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        longCalculations.LongMethod1(); 
    }
}

public class longCalculations
{
    private void LongMethod1()
    {
        // Arbitrarily long code goes here
    }
}
```

I'm doing this in an attempt to keep the `formMainForm` class tidy and be able to split any calculations into manageable chunks. However, I'm encountering problems with using form controls (e.g. check boxes, numeric up-down controls, etc.) in my non-form classes.

If I leave them as is (e.g. `CheckBox1`) I get a *the name does not exist in the current context* error. I searched around and I found that it's because that box is defined in a different class. However, if I change it to `formMainForm.CheckBox1`, the error is now an *object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property*. Again, I looked around and it appears that that is due to the form initialization method not being static.

If I change `public formMainForm()` to `static formMainForm()`, the error now moves to `InitializeComponent();` and I do not know where to go from here. I also tried making an instantiation of the `formMainForm()` method, but that didn't do anything (the code I attempted to use is below. I found it somewhere on this site as an answer to a similar problem).

```
private void formLoader(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shadowrunMainForm runForm = new shadowrunMainForm();
    runForm.Show();
}
```

How can I use the formcontrol names in other classes?

P.S. It is my first post here - I am super sorry if I have missed this question already being asked somewhere. I did search, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

#### EDIT

It seems I hadn't made myself clear - this was just an example of code and my problem is with the second class, not the first one. I have now simplified the code to:

```
public partial class formMainForm : Form
{
    public formMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
}

public class longCalculations
{
    private void LongMethod1()
    {
        List<CheckBox> listOfBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
        listOfBoxes.Add(CheckBox1);
        // The code displays an "object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property" error at this stage. Changing the "CheckBox1" to formMainForm.CheckBox1 doesn't help
        // Arbitrarily long code goes here
    }
}
```

`LongMethod1` works perfectly fine when placed in the `formMainForm` partial class. Moving it to the other form makes it unable to take data from those checkboxes.

Comment: Create an instance of your longCalculations class (Class should be called LongCalculations, btw) and call your method. Or, if the method absolutely must be static, then declare it static and call it that way instead. If it really is a long calculation, then you should be looking at a Task or BackgroundWorker to do that for you, so you don't lock up the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your longCalculations class would not attempt to modify the form directly. Instead it would return an object that the form could use to update its controls.

If you need to access the form directly from the longCalculations class, first change the method to accept an instance of your form

```
public void LongMethod1(formMainForm myForm)
```

Then you can pass the form itself as a parameter

```
var calc = new longCalculations();
calc.LongMethod1(this);
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks! Now it works exactly as I wanted. I presume the  `myForm` can take any name and is just used inside the new method, correct?

Comment: Yes, the name of the method parameter will only be used within that method.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this line `longCalculations.LongMethod1();` is throwing error cause you are trying to access a instance method as if it's a `static` method and as well it's defined as `private` method which won't be accessible outside the class. You need to create an instance of `longCalculations` class before accessing any of it's member or method(s) and mark the method `public` like

```
private void UpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    longCalculations ln = new longCalculations();
    ln.LongMethod1(); 
}

public class longCalculations
{
    public void LongMethod1()
    {
        // Arbitrarily long code goes here
    }
}
```

(OR) If you really want it to be a `static` method then define accordingly with `static` modifier like

```
public class longCalculations
{
    public static void LongMethod1()
    {
        // Arbitrarily long code goes here
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like the way you are trying

Comment: He's trying to call a *private* instance method as if it were a *public* `static` method. And he probably just needs to make it static, if you're correct in assuming that no there are no parameters of any kind being passed in to the method or the `longCalculations` constructor.

Comment: It should be public in either event. And called as a normal public method on an instance, or as a static method, if that's his design requirements.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, that's horrible mistake. Thanks for pointing ... edited answer.

Comment: @Rahul I've added an edit to clarify. That is not the element that causes me problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class longCalculations
{
    public static void LongMethod1()
    {
        // Arbitrarily long code goes here
    }
}
```

If you're going to make a call `longCalculations.LongMethod1();`, then you need to make your class static as such.

Or you leave it as not static method by calling

```
longCalculations lc = new longCalculations()
lc.LongMethod1();
```

As for accessing controls in separate classes, you can pass in the form and make the controls `public` which can be dangerous.

So on your Form.designer.cs, change any control you may have to `public` modifier. Then you would make a call like this...

```
private void UpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    longCalculations.LongMethod1(this); 
}

public void LongMethod1(Form1 form)
{
    // Arbitrarily long code goes here
    form.label1.Text = someString;
    //more settings and whatnot
}
```

Or do something like this:

```
public class longCalculations
{
    public string LongMethod1()
    {
        // Arbitrarily long code goes here

        return myString;
    }
}

longCalculations lc = new longCalculations()
string result = lc.LongMethod1();
this.label1.Text = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your other class, you need to have an *instance* of your `formMainForm` class:

```
var myForm = new formMainForm();
```

Then you can access its members like this:

```
myForm.CheckBox1.Checked = true;
```

Comment: This works perfectly when instanced within a method, thank you! Is there any way to instance it at class level and use in all methods within that class?

Comment: Yes, you would just create a class-level member outside of your methods or properties.  E.g. `private formMainForm _myFirm = new formMainForm();`.